# What is the best way to log in multiple files (one file per request)

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I have a windows service and I want to be able to log each request (and debug messages related to that request) in a file (a file per request).

And also have a generic log were I just log the time and request ID witch I want to store in a single file.

At moment Im using Nlog, and for each new request I create a new logger

```
private Logger CreateNewLogger( string logerName ) {
      var logger = LogManager.GetLogger( logerName );
      var target = new FileTarget {
        Layout = new SimpleLayout( "${time} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${message} | ${exception:format=tostring}" ), AutoFlush = true
      };
      target.FileName = "${basedir}/Logs/${date:format=dd}-${date:format=MM}-${date:format=yyyy}/" + logerName + ".txt";
      var rule = new LoggingRule( logerName, LogLevel.Trace, target );
      var configuration = new LoggingConfiguration();
      configuration.AddTarget( logerName, target );
      configuration.LoggingRules.Add( rule );
      logger.Factory.Configuration = configuration;
      return logger;
    }
```

But doing this doesnt seem correct...as I will end creating an infinite number of loggers and probably create memory issues.

And also the generic Logger is not working propperly when I do

```
LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info( "Received resolve request ID:" + srgMsgId );
```

It still logs in one of the logs I created instead of the general one. why is that?

Anyway, the real wuestion is how can I achieve my objective using nlog?

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, you could use [Configuration variables](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables) to specify the path that the logger should log to.

```
using NLog;

public static class LogService {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Logs");
    private static object lockObject = new object();

    public static void Log(string loggerName)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            LogManager.Configuration.Variables["LoggerName"] = loggerName;
            logger.Log("some message");
        }
    }
}
```

And then in you config file have:

```
<target name="Logs"
    xsi:type="File"
    fileName="${var:LoggerName}.csv">
    <layout xsi:type="CSVLayout">
        <column name="Message" layout="${message}" />
    </layout>
</target>
```

You might be able to do all of this via code rather than requiring the config file setting but this approach works for us.

For the generic log you could have a default value for the LoggerName which logs to the same place each time.